# cannot find protocol declaration for ''

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have searched for related questions, but nothing has worked for me so I will describe my problem. I have two classes. Lets call them ClassA and RootViewController. RootViewController has a button that will trigger an action and delegate it to ClassA. The header for RootController looks like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol RootViewControllerDelegate;

@interface RootViewController : UIViewController <UIPageViewControllerDataSource> {

}

...

@end

@protocol RootViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)buttonPressed : (UIButton *) button;

@end
```

The ClassA header looks like this:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"

@interface RightPanelViewController : UIViewController <RootViewController>

...

@end
```

And I get the error :"Cannot find the protocol declaration for 'RootViewController'. Like I said, I have read some questions related to the same topic, the documentation for delegates, but I'm not able to see what the problem is. I would appreciate some help on this matter.

Comment: There is no protocol named "RootViewController".  It's "RootViewControllerDelegate".

Comment: If you want to subclass RootViewController you do that as `MyController : RootViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your interface line to

```
@interface RightPanelViewController : UIViewController <RootViewControllerDelegate>
```

ie. the name in angle brackets must match exactly with the name in your @protocol definition.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was it, I feel dumb :P.